# ¿Como validar una cantidad de caracteres en un ciclo y 'setear' un valor con PHP?

Tags: formularios, php7

En `php` recibo dos parametros, el `codigo` y la `cantidad`, el `codigo` puede ser `PDO0016890` y la `cantidad` puede ser `10000`que son la cantidad de veces que se incrementara el numero del `codigo`.

```
  $code = $_POST['code'];
  $cant = intval($_POST['cant']);
  $nums = preg_split('/[^0-9]+/i', $code);
  $strings = preg_split('/[^a-zA-Z]+/i', $code);   
  $intN = $nums[1];

 for($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++){
    echo json_encode($intN++);
  }
```

**PROBLEMA:**

cuando recorre el arreglo en la primera 'vuelta' muestra `0016890` pero apartir de la segunda 'vuelta' muestra `16891`, `16892`, etc..., es decir me quita los 00,

> ¿como podria validar para que no me quite esos ceros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te quita los ceros por que al momento de incrementarlo `$intN++` PHP lo transforma a entero.

Si tu número en el código sera siempre de 7 dígitos puedes incrementarlo y agregar los ceros faltantes con [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php)

```
echo json_encode(str_pad($intN++, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

Comment: Excelente Men, gracias por tu interes!.